# Duvida IF com SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Ele esta chamando somente uma opção do if.

1 = >todos usuarios por data = se usuario vazio e data preenchida (so esta chamando essa e msm assim um usuario tem q estar selecionado, o que esta errado o usuario tinha que estar vazio)

2 = > usuario por data = usuario preenchido e data preenchida

3 = >so o usuario = usuario preenchido e data vazia.
Todo o resto nao retorna nada.

o codigo esta assim agora:

```
if (isset($_POST['busca']) && !empty($_POST['busca'])){
  //todos usuarios por periodo
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM assentamentos a, usuarios u, ocorrencias o, problemas p, localizacao l, instituicao i, sistemas s WHERE o.data_abertura BETWEEN '$ymdinicio' AND '$ymdfim' and a.responsavel = u.user_id and a.data = o.data_fechamento and p.prob_id = o.problema and o.local = l.loc_id and i.inst_cod = o.instituicao and s.sis_id = o.sistema ORDER BY o.numero DESC";

        }
        else if(isset($_POST['data_inicial']) && !empty($_POST['data_inicial']) and isset($_POST['data_final']) && !empty($_POST['data_final'])){


    //so usuario 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM assentamentos a, usuarios u, ocorrencias o, problemas p, localizacao l, instituicao i, sistemas s WHERE u.nome = '$busca' and a.responsavel = u.user_id and a.data = o.data_fechamento and p.prob_id = o.problema and o.local = l.loc_id and i.inst_cod = o.instituicao and s.sis_id = o.sistema ORDER BY o.numero DESC";

    }
    else{

    //usuario por periodo
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM assentamentos a, usuarios u, ocorrencias o, problemas p, localizacao l, instituicao i, sistemas s WHERE o.data_abertura BETWEEN '$ymdinicio' AND '$ymdfim' and u.nome = '$busca' and a.responsavel = u.user_id and a.data = o.data_fechamento and p.prob_id = o.problema and o.local = l.loc_id and i.inst_cod = o.instituicao and s.sis_id = o.sistema ORDER BY o.numero DESC";
    }

         print "<table width='100%' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='2' class='full_table_list'>";
         print "<tr class='tabela_cinza'>";
         print "<td align='center' colspan='10'><span class='texto_negrito'>Relat&oacute;rio Geral</span></td>";
         print "</tr>";
         print "<tr>";
         print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_negrito'>Número</span></td>";
         print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_negrito'>Técnico</span></td>";
         print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_negrito'>Problema</span></td>";
         print "<td align='center' width='16%'><span class='texto_negrito'>Descriçao do problema</span></td>";
         print "<td align='center' width='16%'><span class='texto_negrito'>Soluçao do Problema</span></td>";
         print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_negrito'>Área</span></td>";
         print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_negrito'>Unidade</span></td>";
         print "<td align='center' width='12%'><span class='texto_negrito'>Local</span></td>";
         print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_negrito'>Data inicial</span></td>";
         print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_negrito'>Data final</span></td>";
         print "</tr>";
         print "</table>";
          $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
         while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($qr)) {
         print "<form action='' method='post' name='CadInfo' target='_parent' id='CadInfo'>";
         print "<table width='100%' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='2' class='full_table_list'>";
         print "<tr>";
         print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_center'>".$linha['numero']."</span></td>";
         print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_center'>".$linha['nome']."</span></td>";
         print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_center'>".$linha['problema']."</span></td>";
         print "<td align='center' width='16%'><span class='texto_center'>".$linha['descricao']."</span></td>";
         print "<td align='center' width='16%'><span class='texto_center'>".$linha['assentamento']."</span></td>";
         print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_center'>".$linha['sistema']."</span></td>";
         print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_center'>".$linha['inst_nome']."</span></td>";
         print "<td align='center' width='12%'><span class='texto_center'>".$linha['local']."</span></td>";
         print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_center'>".$linha['data_abertura']."</span></td>";
         print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_center'>".$linha['data_fechamento']."</span></td>";
         print "</tr>";
         print "</table>";
         print "</form>";
         }
```

Um otimo final de semana a todos.

Comment: Os blocos , `if, else if e else` são mutuamente excludentes ou seja quando entra em um os demais são ignorados. Somente no `else` a consulta é executa e iterada, parece ser esse o problema.

Comment: Não tenho muito conhecimento, mas acho que problema é que no meio do `if` você utilizou o `and`, ao contrario de um `&&`.

Comment: O operador `and` existe, mas é diferente de `&&`, segue documentação: [Operadores](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: Sao 3 opções de consulta que tenho q por a fincionar, usei if pq ele so tem q executar 1 deles:
1 fazer consulta so pelo usuario
2 fazer consulta do usuario por data
3 fazer consulta de todos os usuarios por data

Comment: Em duas opções falta o `mysql_query()` e o `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

Comment: poderia me dar um exemplo de como deveria ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você teria que fazer da seguinte forma:

```
if ($_POST['busca'] == '-- Selecione o Tecnico --'){
//todos usuarios por periodo
$sql = "SELECT * FROM assentamentos a, usuarios u, ocorrencias o, problemas p, localizacao l, instituicao i, sistemas s WHERE o.data_abertura BETWEEN '$ymdinicio' AND '$ymdfim' and a.responsavel = u.user_id and a.data = o.data_fechamento and p.prob_id = o.problema and o.local = l.loc_id and i.inst_cod = o.instituicao and s.sis_id = o.sistema ORDER BY o.numero DESC";

} else if ((isset($_POST['data_inicial']) && !empty($_POST['data_inicial'])) && (isset($_POST['data_final']) && !empty($_POST['data_final']))){

//so usuario 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM assentamentos a, usuarios u, ocorrencias o, problemas p, localizacao l, instituicao i, sistemas s WHERE u.nome = '$busca' and a.responsavel = u.user_id and a.data = o.data_fechamento and p.prob_id = o.problema and o.local = l.loc_id and i.inst_cod = o.instituicao and s.sis_id = o.sistema ORDER BY o.numero DESC";

} else {

//usuario por periodo
$sql = "SELECT * FROM assentamentos a, usuarios u, ocorrencias o, problemas p, localizacao l, instituicao i, sistemas s WHERE o.data_abertura BETWEEN '$ymdinicio' AND '$ymdfim' and u.nome = '$busca' and a.responsavel = u.user_id and a.data = o.data_fechamento and p.prob_id = o.problema and o.local = l.loc_id and i.inst_cod = o.instituicao and s.sis_id = o.sistema ORDER BY o.numero DESC";
}


 print "<table width='100%' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='2' class='full_table_list'>";
 print "<tr class='tabela_cinza'>";
 print "<td align='center' colspan='10'><span class='texto_negrito'>Relatório Geral</span></td>";
 print "</tr>";
 print "<tr>";
 print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_negrito'>Número</span></td>";
 print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_negrito'>Técnico</span></td>";
 print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_negrito'>Problema</span></td>";
 print "<td align='center' width='16%'><span class='texto_negrito'>Descriçao do problema</span></td>";
 print "<td align='center' width='16%'><span class='texto_negrito'>Soluçao do Problema</span></td>";
 print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_negrito'>Área</span></td>";
 print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_negrito'>Unidade</span></td>";
 print "<td align='center' width='12%'><span class='texto_negrito'>Local</span></td>";
 print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_negrito'>Data inicial</span></td>";
 print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_negrito'>Data final</span></td>";
 print "</tr>";
 print "</table>";
     // $qr = mysql_query($sql, $sql2, $sql3) or die(mysql_error());
 while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($qr)) {
    print "<form action='' method='post' name='CadInfo' target='_parent' id='CadInfo'>";
    print "<table width='100%' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='2' class='full_table_list'>";
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_center'>".$linha['numero']."</span></td>";
    print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_center'>".$linha['nome']."</span></td>";
    print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_center'>".$linha['problema']."</span></td>";
    print "<td align='center' width='16%'><span class='texto_center'>".$linha['descricao']."</span></td>";
    print "<td align='center' width='16%'><span class='texto_center'>".$linha['assentamento']."</span></td>";
    print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_center'>".$linha['sistema']."</span></td>";
    print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_center'>".$linha['inst_nome']."</span></td>";
    print "<td align='center' width='12%'><span class='texto_center'>".$linha['local']."</span></td>";
    print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_center'>".$linha['data_abertura']."</span></td>";
    print "<td align='center' width='8%'><span class='texto_center'>".$linha['data_fechamento']."</span></td>";
    print "</tr>";
    print "</table>";
    print "</form>";
 }
```

Repare que a impressão dos resultados deve ficar fora do if else, senão ele só vai imprimir naquele contexto.

Comment: vlw! ele esta chamando umas das opções que preciso falta ver agora onde estou errando nas outras 2...

Comment: Ele esta chamando somente uma opção do if.

1 = >todos usuarios por data = se usuario vazio e data preenchida (so esta chamando essa e msm assim um usuario tem q estar selecionado, o que esta errado o usuario tinha que estar vazio)
 
2 = > usuario por data  = usuario preenchido e data preenchida
 
3 = >so o usuario = usuario preenchido e data vazia
 
todo o resto nao retorna nada.

Comment: Eu fiz uma correção no bloco do else if, verifique se funciona agora. Reparei que o else if faz a condição caso exista a data inicial e final definida. E em sua descrição você informa que seria para buscar apenas um usuário. Acredito estar invertido suas condições. Verifique isso aí também